# Function generates random number in array

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers

I am trying to create a function that creates random number for a array.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ROW 22
#define COL 80


void display(int life[ROW][COL]){
    for(int i = 0; i<ROW; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<COL; j++){
            printf("%d",life[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void initialize_board(int life[ROW][COL]){
    for(int i = 0; i< ROW;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<COL ; j++){
            life[ROW][COL] = rand()%2;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    srand(getpid());
    printf("PID: %d\n",getpid());
    int life[22][80] = {0};
    initialize_board(life);
    display(life);
    return 0;
}
```

However I got output are 0s not randomly assigned to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
life[ROW][COL] = rand()%2;
```

use

```
life[i][j] = rand()%2;
```

inside that loop.

As it stands, you're writing all random values to the same (invalid) memory address a bit behind the end of the array.

Comment: @Akrios Be more polite to people, including yourself.

Comment: Rest assured that there's not one among us who hasn't made similar mistakes before. Except those who are just starting out and haven't written any code yet; they will make them in the future. :P

Answer (score 0):

`[ROW][COL`] are constanst, so you're writing always in the same (invalid, as Wintermute mentioned) cell.  So you had to use the variables `i` and `j`
kind regards